# geoserver css point stacker

Tags: geoserver-css-module

I´ve read this article about geoservers pointStacker transformation:
http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/cartography/rt/pointstacker.html

Is this function implemented in geoserver css? If so can one provide a simple example?

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer rendering functions are independent of the styling language used. For examples of function usage in CSS see this [page](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/examples/transformation.html). 
So something like (completely untested):

```
*{
   vec:PointStacker(parameter(data),parameter(cellsize,30),parameter(outputBBOX(env(wms_bbox)),....
  }
```

Comment: Iant, it´s you again who comes to help. I´ve read the documentaion but haven´t read something like this. Are you the author of the css extension?Anyway I will give it a try and come back. Big thanks.

Comment: The link provided by Ian Turton appears to be broken. This is the new [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/examples/transformation.html)